# How to trigger a event with event object in backbone.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, backbone.js

**HTML**

```
<input type="radio" name="tools" value="marks" id="marks" class="tools">Marks
    <input type="radio" name="tools" value="Rating" id="Rating" class="rdbChange">Rating
            <input type="radio" name="tools" value="CheckList" id="CheckList" class="rdbChange">CheckList
```

**BACKBONE.js**

Here I have defined an event in events

```
"change .rdbChange" : "loadAssessmentSettings"
```

which triggers a function with event object

```
loadAssessmentSettings : function(ev){
var assessedTool= $(ev.currentTarget).val();
}
```

Now I need to triiger this change event from another function, I tried like this

```
triggerChange: function(){
    trigger( "rdbChange" );
}
```

which doesn't pass the event parameter to the `loadAssessmentSettings` method.
How can I pass this event object?

Answer (score 0):

You need to trigger a `change` event that is on `.rdbChange`. So you can do:

`$('.rdbChange').trigger('change');`

In your example, `instance.trigger('change');` might work but your question doesn't make it clear what `instance` references.

Comment: instance was my current Backbone.View object. I just did `instance =this` in the render method. 
so can I use `$(ev.currentTarget).val();` to get the value from ev object with `.trigger('change');` ?